# php if, and, or : multiple variables to check. Working, but getting variable not defined errors

Tags: php, if-statement, drupal

Basically I'm trying to check if any variable exists, if so, then run the snippet regardless if the others exist or not.

I'm using:

```
if ($a1 || $a2 || $a3 || $a4):
$a = "success";
endif;
```

If only `$a4` exists, this works and set's the `$a` variable fine. However, I'm getting variable not defined error's for anything before `$a4`.

A different variable is set if the `$a0` variable doesn't exist (NULL):

```
if (!empty($a0) && $a1 || $a2 || $a3 || $a4) :
$a-alt = "no0success";
endif;
```

This code is working fine. However, it's giving me the variable not defined error.

Comment: You can't use - in a php variable. change it to `$a_alt` and as  @AkshayHegde says in his answer, try and use `isset()`

Comment: Ahh, I edited the names to make it easier before I posted it here.
Didn't press shift hard enough I guess. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function, Try something like this

```
if( isset($variable) ){
   // do so and so....
}else
{
   // define variable
   $variable = 'foo';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
This worked perfectly. I got it working doing this. No errors or anything.
I'll be remembering this one :)

Works as expected, so posting it up.

`if (isset($a1) || isset($a2) || isset($a3) || isset($a4)):
$a = "success";
endif;`
.................................
`if (!empty($a0) && isset($a1) || isset($a2) || isset($a3) || isset($a4)) :
$a_alt = "no0success";
endif;`

Comment: Glad to know that it worked,  keep learning, all the best John.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if each variable is set. PHP's short-circuit logic will ensure that you don't get any errors:

```
if ((isset($a1) && $a1) ||
    (isset($a2) && $a2) ||
    (isset($a3) && $a3) ||
    (isset($a4) && $a4)) 
    $a = "success";
endif;
```

Note that since `&&` has higher precedence than `||` the additional braces are redundant, but IMHO they increase the snippet's readability.